# Exercise 32 from Bernard Schutz

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, vector-fields, gauge

The exercise
[image]

In Bernard Schutz's 'General Relativity, there is an exercise, I don't understand how to start with.

To develop a TT Gauge, we should use the given transformation. But somehow I am confused about how to even start this exercise.

I tried using the following equation:
$$
\bar{h}_{\mu \nu} =\bar{h}_{\mu \nu}^{old} -\xi_{\mu , \nu} - \xi_{\nu,\mu} + \eta_{\mu \nu}\xi^{\rho}_{,\rho}
$$

But I don't understand how to only use terms up to order $1/r$ because all my derivatives are of $1/r^2$ and higher

Comment: Hint: you'll have to take derivatives of $B^{\alpha}$, also $x/r^{2}$ is of order $\frac{1}{r}$

Comment: I thought $B^\alpha$ is slowly varying, doesn't that mean its derivative is equal to 0? Also I don't understand how to calculate the last term, that is $\eta_{\mu \nu}\xi^{\rho}_{,\rho}$.

Comment: Don't you have $\partial_r (e^{i \Omega(r - t)}/r) \approx -\partial_t (e^{i \Omega(r - t)}/r) \approx i \Omega e^{i \Omega(r - t)}/r$?